# Select a column without 8 first characters? "(" is not allowed, "( " is expected

Tags: abap

I add this SQL statement in my code but there is an error

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (NODENAME,9,LENGTH(NODENAME) - 1 )
FROM RSMHIERNODE 
WHERE HIEID = 'HRJPUD'

INTO TABLE @lt_commentdata.
```

where `NODENAME` is a column in my table.

The error is below :

> "(" is not allowed here. "( " is expected.

Have you any idea how can I solve this ?

I want to select the values of `NODENAME` without the 8 first characters at the beginning of each string on `NODENAME`.

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: yes , thank you :))

Answer (score 2):

ABAP is whitespace-sensitive and the spaces are missing after and before the brackets:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( nodename, 9, LENGTH( nodename ) - 1 )
       FROM rsmhiernode
       WHERE ...
       INTO ...
```

Comment: when i replace it but your code , the function length is red and still the same problem

Comment: @emilie these features were added to OpenSQL in version 7.50, if you are on a lower version the only option you have is to read the data into an internal table first and then manipulate it. Relevant SAP help page: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=ABAPSQL_EXPR.htm

Comment: yeah , i tried it by using internal table but still same problem .

Comment: The problem with the length parameter is not solved with ABAP 7.50, it's solved starting with **[ABAP 7.55](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_string_func.htm)**. Before 7.55, you can only use constants or host expressions, not SQL expressions. @emilie that's a different question, please post a new one, thanks!